# Why after parenting, the mesh lays down while the armature stands up?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, vertices

I am trying to make a stethoscope
Before parenting
[image]

After parenting
[image]

How do we make it so both of them are vertical?

Comment: Have you applied the rotation to both armature and object (Ctrl-a > Rotation in Object mode)?

Comment: what rotation, what dose the rotation do?

Comment: oh, Thanks! It helped, explain to me why is it like that?

Comment: Best to read the Blender manual for that one: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data